# How do I write the contents of a variable to a file in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript

I saved the contents of a search I made on website to a variable. I know it is in there as I can print the result to the terminal.

However I need to grab this information for future use to compare to other results, and needs to be formatted. Is this possible in Nightwatch?

This is the code that saves the text:

```
'saving query results' : function (browser) {
    browser 
        .useXpath()   
        .getText(('//*[@id="messages"]/code'), function(result) {
        console.log(result) 
        })
```

I have tried to find a solution on google but cannot find anything doing what I need it to. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you take a look at `fs` module?

Comment: show a bit of what you have tried so we can help you better

Comment: I have tried the redirection method (>) to save the variable that holds the text to the file but that doesn't seem to work with Nightwatch. I tried automating a right click to save the body of text.

Comment: I have also tried to write it to a .js file instead of txt but that didn't work (using redirection) And as the body of the text changes with each search I cant hard code it.